# Ubuntu 18.04 not showing maximum usable ram

Tags: ram, amd-processor, msi, amd-ryzen, v-ram

Specs -

```
CPU - Ryzen 5 2400G
Motherboard - MSI B450 gaming plus
RAM - Corsair Vengeance 8GB x 2
I am Using two displays - HDMI && DVI
```

I installed ubuntu 18.04
and it shows only 13.7GB ram out of 16GB

[image]

And When I use only one ram stick it shows 5.8 GB out of 8GB

I was on windows and there RAM was 14+GB

[image]

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

Output

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 256 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x000E
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000F
    Error Information Handle: 0x0015
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: Unknown
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Unknown
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000F
    Error Information Handle: 0x0017
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 1
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: CMK8GX4M1D3000C16   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1067 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000F
    Error Information Handle: 0x001A
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: Unknown
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: Unknown
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: Unknown
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: Unknown
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000F
    Error Information Handle: 0x001C
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 1
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: CMK8GX4M1D3000C16   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1067 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

Answer (score 4):

May want to check the "Integrated Graphics Setting"  in Peripherals (I have Gigabyte motherboard, your settings may be different on MSI) on your BIOS. This setting controls the amount of RAM allocated to the GPU on the 2400G, when set to auto on my motherboard, it allocates around 2 GB of Ram. When all the overhead is taken into account I have about 13.9 GB left from my 2x8 (16 Gb) Ram.  If you have a dedicated GPU unit separate from the 2400G, you can force the Ram to be smaller through this BIOS setting.  On my rig, I have found that "Auto" on the Integrated Graphics Setting gives the best overall performance, as I do not have a separate Video Card.

Comment: may be u r right. because when I only use one stick then it shows 5.8GB. 5.8+2 = 7.8. and 2x8, 13.7+2 = 15.7. but in windows I was able to use full ram. i don't know how!!!!